# React warning: Did not properly initialize state during construction

Tags: reactjs

I use `getDerivedStateFromProps` from react 16.3. Why does react show this warning?

`Did not properly initialize state during construction. Expected state to be an object, but it was undefined.`

Demo on [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mLJmrK?editors=0011)

```
class TestComponent extends React.PureComponent {
    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {
        const {record,} = nextProps;

        return {
            title: record ? record.title : '',
        };
    }


    render() {
        const {title} = this.state;

        return (
            <div>{title}</div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you need to set initial value for states:

```
class TestComponent extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
    title: ''
   };
 }
// rest of your code
```

Or, using [ES7 syntax](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/): (If you're creating app with create-react-app, this will be supported)

```
class TestComponent extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
   title: ''
  }
// rest of your code
```

You may be interested to read this [blog](https://medium.com/@fakiolinho/reactjs-and-es7-bbedb9862e61) on medium.

Comment: I know why they did it but I can see this issue becoming annoying when a component doesn't need to have a state. Having experimented with prop values, `componentDidUpdate` does not receive the same props as `getDerivedStateFromProps` so if the latter one becomes the only reliable way to get latest props then this means having to add state to components which previously didn't need it.

Comment: my code doesn't have any state, still getting the warning. guide me to resolve it.

Comment: @Goutham.T.J Linking a fiddle may help to debug. If there's no state, there's should be no this error. Error should be something else?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal The error happens because of this line in react-dom:

`
if (typeof ctor.getDerivedStateFromProps === 'function' && state === null)
`

Notice that state in a React component can be null if you're using redux and implementing getDerivedStateFromProps. The problem goes away if you initialize state as {} in the constructor of the component.